# Low quality posts bug

Tags: bug, status-completed, review, low-quality-posts

I opened a question (bug report) earlier this day about LQ Posts bug (getting same posts multiple times), but I've deleted it, beacause I realized that those posts can be very similar, not the same.

Later, I saw other posts to appear twice, but I don't have any proof of that.
Maybe I'm not the only who noticed this, because I reached 2000 rep today, there are other people who reviews posts for a longer time than me.

---

Here's another bug: I noticed 3 times that my reviewed-posts count is getting lower and lower.
I have screenshot evidences here:

> [image: Before: count at 514 (6:25 PM)]

> [image: After: count at 474 (8:32 PM)]

Comment: I think your "reviewed posts" count is decreasing because deleted posts are not included in that. That doesn't seem the right way to count, so if my suspicion is correct, that would be a bug report/feature request.

Comment: @DanielFischer If I've reviewed 500 posts, that means I've reviewed 500 posts. Not 400.

Comment: Yes. But I suspect deleted posts vanish from the counter too, not only from the site.

Comment: It seems odd that deleted posts wouldn't count in the reviews, as it could very well be a review that led to the post's deletion. If a review helped keep the site clean and eliminate the worst of posts, then it should be counted, IMHO.

Comment: @jmort253 I completely agree, but that's the only explanation of the decreasing count I can think of at the moment.

Comment: I have seen the decrease as well. The other day I was just under 1000 in total, so I reviewed a couple more just to pass the magic number. The next morning it was 975!

Comment: And, BTW, I have also seen the recurring posts and thought it must be a bug. Even if some poster has 5 copies of the same low quality post, what are the odds for two of these coming up when drawing 100 posts randomly(?) from 70k posts?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This was an issue due to our review task invalidation scheduled task.  Basically it looks for tasks completed too fast - however the issue here is that it wasn't in sync with the client side check.  After the next build review items will no longer be invalidated incorrectly.