# Keep phantom review points even if actual post itself may be deleted

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, review, deleted-questions

It's a bit unfair, in my opinion, that we lose a review point if a question we reviewed gets deleted.

I think the review count should show the amount of questions you reviewed and not the amount of questions you reviewed and didn't get deleted.

Comment: Review point, thou art Loosed!

Comment: Agreed. This is how total vote counts work now, I'd imagine reviews should count the same.

Comment: Are you talking about voting to delete from the review page?  Because I think that definitely *should* count if the post gets deleted.

Comment: A related question [Low quality posts bug](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/140747/low-quality-posts-bug#comment397608_140747)

Answer (score 9):

If you really made such an amazing edit that was worthy of you keeping your rep, would the question have been deleted?

I'll accept an amend of this that you get to keep it when the owner deletes it with an accepted answer, but otherwise, you lose. (Because sometimes the OP is a douche, but rarely)

And if you go "well, it would've been worthwhile, if it hadn't been {close reason worthy}" then I really have to look at you nice and hard.

Comment: I frequently stare at the question trying to figure what's up with this wall of text. Then, I edit it, fix spelling, formatting, anything I can think of. After edit, I look at it again and clearly see whether to closevote it or upvote. In cases like this, editing helps me make decision, even when the decision is to close

Comment: Ok, but if you decided after that it was a sunk question, are you really looking to keep the rep? I mean, yeah, you invested time, but then you gave up your investment by deciding that this was a _____ Q

Comment: hard to tell. Not that I am addicted to the edit-rep at all; but keeping it doesn't feel wrong to me either, even in the close-case. Y'know mind plays funny tricks to indulge self: eg I can say my edit helped others to make close/delete decision easier and because of that, rep on closed / edited question is deserved.

Comment: Good points, definitely, and worthy of uptick (there's your indulged contribution ;-) )

Answer (score 5):

I disagree.  We don't get to keep credit for edits that are subsequently deleted or if the post is further edited by someone else.  I think the same should apply to reviews.  If I accept or reject an edit and the post gets deleted anyway, it's debatable whether I've really added value to the site.  Both edits and reviews should be geared towards improving content to the point where it can stay on the site.  If you see something in review that shouldn't be here at all (and you can't *improve* it enough that it should), don't review it.  Just go vote to close or delete it instead.

Comment: I think that's the point of the question, I *think* Lucas is saying that in the Review system (e.g. Low Quality Posts) if you vote-to-delete a LQP, and it *does* end up being deleted, your "Review" for that post gets removed with it.

Comment: But [*votes* on deleted posts are included in our counts](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/117846/votes-cast-should-include-votes-on-deleted-contributions/123048#123048), shouldn't reviews continue to count as well?

Comment: @jadarnel27 They're two different things.  Downvotes on deleted posts have some value, as explained by Nick.  I don't think edits (and voting to accept/reject edits) on deleted posts has the same value.

Comment: Sorry, I think I'm confused about what, exactly, the OP is asking (which queue they're in, which actions they're taking).  I agree with your comment, this definitely warrants being handled differently based on which thing we're discussing (edits, edit votes, close votes, delete votes, etc).

Comment: One option is to remove the "Top Reviewers All time" from the Stats tab if it doesn't show the number of posts actually reviewed. What use does it have now?

Comment: @jadarnel27 I assumed it was the new beta page for [reviewing suggested edits](http://stackoverflow.com/review-beta/suggested-edits/167498), but now I'm not sure either.  :)

Comment: I think it's the issue of http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/140747/low-quality-posts-bug#comment397588_140747 here too.

Answer (score 3):

There was a bug earlier listed here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/141160/2 that was fixed.  We were invalidating review items based on the speed of the review however we aren't having this issue any more.